# Rails 4 model.new with custom date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails 4.

When trying to create a new model, the following works:

`MyModel.new(myDate: '2015-10-30')`

However, this doesn't work:

`MyModel.new(myDate: '10-30-2015')`

How can I make the second work? In my initializers, I have set the default rails date format to:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default]="%m/%d/%Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default]="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
```

This date format is registered, and all dates are returned in the above format. It still doesn't seem to affect the date format when creating a NEW model though.

FYI, I'm aware I can call `Date.parse()` or some other conversion method on the string prior to creating the new model. I am looking for a way to make the second work without having to convert the string to some other form prior to `.new` being called.

Comment: Might be a typo, but the date format you've set as `:default` is different to the one you've used in your example as what you want to parse. Worth clarifying if that is a typo.

Comment: Boomball, worth clarifying indeed. That was the issue - Thanks for the help, feel free to post an answer :)